# Postfix - adding domain + forwarding setting

Tags: redirect, postfix-mta

I have a question as to postfix add a new domain to be able to it to send and receive e-mails?
How to redirect all emails sent to this domain went to an external email address?

Regards,
Darek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a domain will be adding it to `mydestination= example.com` in `main.cf`

the second question is called a "catch all"

Mapping is done using `/etc/postfix/virtual` file.

```
vim /etc/postfix/virtual
```

Append code as follows, replacing domain and emailusername with actual values:

```
@yourdomain.com emailusername
```

Save and close the file. Run following command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

Also make sure you have following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

If you just added above, line reload postfix:

```
service postfix reload
```